# How to create a new Data Extension using Queries?

Tags: query, dataextensions

My goal is to use a master data extension which has all contacts regardless of the possibility of sending emails. So I would like to use Queries to filter this Data Extension and create a new one with only the contacts who has accepted to receive an email. 
How can I create this DE from the master using queries? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think SFMC has the functionality to create a new Data Extension by using a query activity in automation studio.
But since you need need to just filter your master data extension, I recommend you create a duplicate of this master data extension, 
then you can write the query:

**select {{specify your required column names}}
from master_data_extension
where flag_opt_in == "YES"**

Then for the target Data extension you can choose your pre-build data extension which append/update/overwrite as per your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much!!